# Number picker only allowing zero as value

Tags: java, android, android-number-picker

I am making an app that utilizes the numberpicker. What happens is when I try to create the numberpicker and set its attributes, it just simply won't do anything. The only value it allows is zero, and you can't scroll the numbers with it either. After a lot of google searches, I'm quite certain that I put the min/max-value methods in the right order.

I would appreciate some guidance of what I'm doing wrong.

source:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;

public class Start extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        NumberPicker minutePicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.minutePicker);
        minutePicker.setMaxValue(100);
        minutePicker.setMinValue(0);
        minutePicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

        NumberPicker secondPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.secondPicker);
        secondPicker.setMaxValue(60);
        secondPicker.setMinValue(0);
        secondPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);



    }
}
```

**edit:**
Added XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/twoPickers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.listifymusic.listifymusic.Start">

    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/secondPicker"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/minutePicker"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/minutePicker"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/minutePicker"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/minutePicker" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/minutePicker"
        android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="102dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: probably issue is in layout xml

Comment: The minValue defaults to 0, by the way

Comment: Your code seems fine. Share your activity_start.xml code.

Comment: Editet the main post now with the XML-source.

Comment: Everything looks good... Have you tried rebuilding your project? `build` -> `rebuild`

Comment: Just to clarify, you are testing your app on a device / emulator, not just using the preview window right?

Comment: Tried doing it again, still won't work. Are there other alternatives for the numberpicker that I can try to implement?

Comment: Doing it on the emulater, can try to attatch my physical phone and check if it works

Comment: Emulator should be fine... I copied your code in an empty project and it works just fine. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Could it be API-level perhaps? Will come back with results

Comment: `public class Start extends AppCompatActivity {` are you sure your start activity is the launcher activity? Could you have another activity called MainActivity that is being called instead?

Comment: I just added a NumberPicker with match_parent, wrap_content, and no margin or alignment. Works fine.

Comment: Based on the fact you named one "minutePicker", you should be aware that there actually is a `TimePicker`, if that is what you are going for. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: Just copied your exact code and layout - also working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your activity is set as launcher activity in your manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".Start">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've started some other Activity that is essentially doing only this.

```
public class SomeOtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    }
}
```

---

In other words, the code you have should work if you start the `Start` activity.